# Как влияет запятая на смысл предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

> Cупруги прекращают режим общей собственности на имущество и
>   устанавливают режим раздельной собственности на любое имущество
>   полученное супругами в период брака с момента его заключения, до
>   момента его расторжения.

Comment: Запятая не требует пробела. Как вы сами отвечаете на этот вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Cупруги прекращают режим общей собственности на имущество и устанавливают режим раздельной собственности на любое имущество, полученное супругами (когда?) **в период брака** (когда именно?) **с момента его заключения  до момента его расторжения.**

**Указанная запятая не ставится в обязательном порядке,** но на смысл она не влияет: сочетание "с момента его заключения  до момента его расторжения" — это единая по смыслу конструкция, которая уточняет временной период брачных отношений.

Answer (score 1):

> Как влияет запятая на смысл предложения?

Формальный ответ на формальный вопрос: никак не влияет. Просто пунктуационная ошибка.

Но, как понимаю, вопрос-то не в этом.

> Я как раз и есть заинтересованная сторона

Юристы эту запятую проигнорируют. Это даже для куда более спорных случаев верно, а тут, на мой скромный взляд, даже зацепиться не за что.

> я ни с чем осталась

Тогда вы не по адресу. Вам нужна текстологическая (семантическая) экспертиза, а не частное мнение участников проекта, далеких от юридического крючкотворства.

Спросите тут.
http://rusexpert.ru/

> Гильдия оказывает эффективную помощь в проведении ***лингвистической*** и
>   автороведческой экспертизы спорных русских текстов (публикаций,
>   ***документов***, теле- и радиопрограмм)...

(Курсив мой - М.)

Но особо не обнадеживайте себя.

Answer (score 0):

Если бы не было явных пунктуационных ошибок (нет запятой в начале причастного оборота, после слова "имущество"; пробел перед запятой), то имеющаяся сейчас запятая дала бы повод юристу заинтересованной стороны трактовать окончание предложения как уточнение к действию "устанавливают", а смысл трактовать так, что *режим раздельной собственности* длится "только до момента расторжения брака". Для устранения неоднозначности (в предположении, что это из соглашения при разводе, а не из условий брачного договора) можно, убрав запятую, явно указать на исчисление "периода брака":

> ... имущество, полученное супругами в период брака, **исчисляемый** с
>   момента его заключения до момента его расторжения.

Comment: Уважаемый @Alex_ander! Я как раз и есть заинтересованная сторона и для меня эта запятая соломинка для утопающего-развод состоялся и я ни с чем осталась в том случае, если эту запятую можно легко убрать. Казнить нельзя помиловать.

Comment: Проблема в том, что при наличии явных пунктуационных ошибок (как здесь) любую имеющуюся запятую можно поставить под сомнение как случайно поставленную. С принципами юридической экспертизы таких текстов я не знаком, поэтому не могу сказать, как будут трактовать текст с ошибками. Если же исходить из здравого смысла, то в конце предложения просто уточнены начало и окончание "периода брака".

Comment: @Jasmin Благодарю за мнение. Указанная запятая не ставится в обязательном порядке, но на смысл она не влияет: сочетание "с момента его заключения до момента его расторжения" — это единая по смыслу конструкция, которая уточняет временной период брачных отношений. А зачем уточнять то, что и так понятно: период брака и есть промежуток от момента его заключения до расторжения.

Comment: @Jasmin Благодарю за мнение. Указанная запятая не ставится в обязательном порядке, но на смысл она не влияет: сочетание "с момента его заключения до момента его расторжения" — это единая по смыслу конструкция, которая уточняет временной период брачных отношений. А зачем уточнять то, что и так понятно: период брака и есть промежуток от момента его заключения до расторжения.